# How to add borders to an image so that its size be divisible by 4

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick

I try to add borders to an image using ImageMagic to make its dimension divisible by 4. I wrote:

```
image_files=( "$alldir"/*.png )

current="${image_files[0]}"
page_height=$(identify -format "%h" $current)
page_width=$(identify -format "%w" $current)

border_x=$((4-(page_width%4) + 40))
border_y=$((4-(page_height%4) + 40))
```

After using `border` command, I would have:

```
page_height= page_height + 2*border_y
page_width= page_width + 2*border_x
```

The final `page_height` and `page_width` are expected to be divisible by 4 but the width is an odd number. What's the problem with my approach?

Comment: You don't show how you try to add the border! Your code implies you are resizing the image (since you calculate a new width and height) but you will need the `!` after the new size else it will resize whilst maintaining aspect ratio. Show your code and I'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calculate the width of the border on each side and do resizing and padding, it's often easier to calculate the total size of the bordered image, set the background colour and change the extent of the image to the new size. So, say I start with this image which is 181x149 pixels:

[image]

Now, I want a 40 pixel border, so I set a shell variable:

```
border=40
```

then I can centre the image on a yellow background like this:

```
magick input.png -background yellow -gravity center -extent "%[fx:w-w%4+2*$border]x%[fx:h-h%4+2*$border]" +repage result.png
```

[image]

---

If you have an older **ImageMagick** v6 release that doesn't like doing the maths, you can let your shell do it:

```
border=40
# Get width and height in one go with a bash "process substitution"
read w h < <(identify -format "%w %h" input.png)
convert input.png -background yellow -gravity center -extent "$((w-w%4+2*$border))x$((h-h%4+2*$border))" +repage result.png
```

Comment: I also thought about resizing after adding borders. I just don't know if your code guarantees that the width will be divisible by 4?

Comment: Have faith! :-) `w%4` tells you what is left over after you divide by 4, so if you subtract that from `w` you will round down to the nearest 4. Try it on some different size images.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is doubling your calculated border size.
Say page_width=1, then border_x=43, and your final page_width=1+2*43=87

If you want a border of ~40 on both sides, you probably want the following:

```sh
border_x=$((4-(page_width%4) + 2*40))
border_y=$((4-(page_height%4) + 2*40))

page_height=$((page_height + border_y))
page_width=$((page_width + border_x))
```

Comment: When borders are added to the image they are added in two sides, so based on your code 83 will be added to 1 => the final width = 2*83+1 which is an odd number again.

Comment: @Ahmad Please review the solution: say page_width=1, then border_x=83, and your final page_width=1+83=84.

Comment: Yeah, resizing can solve the problem, but I asked if I can do it with bordering, which is not easy, because borders are added in both sides.

Comment: @Ahmad your original question was 'I try to add borders to an image using ImageMagic to make its dimension divisible by 4.  The final `page_height` and `page_width` are expected to be divisible by 4 but the width is an odd number. What's the problem with my approach?'.  I believe the solution shows where the problem is.  If you have another follow-up question, please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: When you calculate the page_width after adding border you wrote `page_width=$((page_width + border_x))` which is incorrect. it must be `page_width=$((page_width + 2*border_x))`. Why? because after using command `border`, borders are added in two sides! so the resulting `page_width` is what I wrote. However, if you use `resize` it works, but my question was about bordering. In fact I myself solved my problem by adding first borders and then resizing it. The other answer using `extent` is also a solution.